# Regex expressions for matching comparisons

Tags: regex, search, comparison

Is it possible to create a regular expression that matches a comparison such as less than or greater than? For example, match all dollar values less than $500.

One way I would use this would be on online stores that list many products on a single page but do not provide a way to sort by price. I found a search page by regex extension for Chrome and am trying to figure out if there is a way I can use a regex to match any strings on the page beginning with a dollar sign followed by any number less than a number that I specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you `\$[1-4]?\d?\d\b`.

**Explanation:**

```
r"""
\$       # Match the character “$” literally
[1-4]    # Match a single character in the range between “1” and “4”
   ?        # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d       # Match a single digit 0..9
   ?        # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\d       # Match a single digit 0..9
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
"""
```

Comment: Note that less then 500 means upto 499.99 but not more :> Also you didnt account for cents values.

Comment: @BenjaminUdinktenCate This regex can be easily modified if the cents values are also needed to be considered.

Comment: this also matches values over $500 Edit: not true anymore, sorry :)

Comment: @micheleb Can you please give example which this matches above 500? I do not think this matches any value above 500.

Comment: I didn't refresh before you added the word boundary at the end

Comment: @micheleb Not a problem. I wish SO updates answers asyncrhonously :P

Answer (score 1):

This could do what you need: `^(\$[1-4]?\d?\d)$`. This will match any value between `$1` and `$499`.

As mentioned above, if you would like to match even decimal values you could use something like so: `^(\$[1-4]?\d?\d(\.\d{2})?)$`. That being said, numeric validation should ideally be done using actual mathematical operations, and not regular expressions.

Comment: @BartKiers: Yes you are correct. I have amended my result and provided another one to cater for cents.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this is overly complicated, but it will also match any value strictly less than 500

```
\$[1-4]\d{2}(\.\d{2})?$|\$\d{1,2}(\.\d{2})?$
```

if you need to match `$500` as well, add another `|\$500(\.00)?$`

This matches:

```
\$            the dollar symbol
[1-4]         followed by a digit between 1 and 4
\d{2}         followed by exactly 2 digits
(\.\d{2})?    optionally --> ()? followed by a dot --> \. and exactly 2 digits
$             followed by end of line (may be replaced with \b for word boundaries)
|             or
\$\d{1,2}     the dollar symbol followed by any two digits
(\.\d{1,2})?$ again optionally followed by cents, followed by end of line
```